# How to allow string with letters, numbers, period, hyphen, and underscore?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression, that allow to create string with the small and big letters + numbers - **a-zA-z0-9** and also with the chars: `.-_`

How do I make such a regex?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following regex should be what you are looking for (explanation below):

```
\A[-\w.]*\z
```

The following character class should match only the characters that you want to allow:

```
[-a-zA-z0-9_.]
```

You could shorten this to the following since `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-z0-9_]`:

```
[-\w.]
```

Note that to include a literal `-` in your character class, it needs to be first character because otherwise it will be interpreted as a range (for example `[a-d]` is equivalent to `[abcd]`).  The other option is to escape it with a backslash.

Normally `.` means any character except newlines, and you would need to escape it to match a literal period, but this isn't necessary inside of character classes.

The `\A` and `\z` are anchors to the beginning and end of the string, otherwise you would match strings that contain any of the allowed characters, instead of strings that contain **only** the allowed characters.

The `*` means zero or more characters, if you want it to require one or more characters change the `*` to a `+`.

Comment: I like your explanation but this doesn't work to me. @seamus-abshere's answer works great.

Answer (score 4):

`/\A[\w\-\.]+\z/`

- `\w` means alphanumeric (case-insensitive) and "_"
- `\-` means dash
- `\.` means period
- `\A` means beginning (even "stronger" than `^`)
- `\z` means end (even "stronger" than `$`)

for example:

```
>> 'a-zA-z0-9._' =~ /\A[\w\-\.]+\z/
=> 0 # this means a match
```

**UPDATED** thanks [phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) for improvement

Comment: You might want to wrap that in `/\A...\z/` so that the OP can ensure that an invalid string with a valid substring is not matched. Also, `i` is unnecessary when you're using `\w`.